# Puppet realizing defined users

Tags: puppet

Mostly as a learning exercise, I'm trying to use defines to create users. There are no errors, but the user doesn't get created. Adding calls to notify makes me suspect the problem is the order of execution (but it may also be my newbness elsewhere). I'm using Puppet 2.7.9.

Here's my code.

```
    # manifests/nodes.pp
    node /song.*/ {
      include users
      User <| group == developers |>
    }

    # modules/users/manifests/init.pp
    class users {
      include users::people
    }

    # modules/users/manifests/people.pp 
    class users::people {
      require groups
      @users::account { "michael":
          username => "michael",
          name     => "Michael C. Harris",
          uid      => 1000,
          gid      => "developers",
          password => '{encrypted password}',
          groups   => [ "wheel" ],
      }
    }

    # modules/groups/manifests/init.pp
    class groups {
      Group { ensure => present }
      group { "wheel":
        gid => 10;
      }
      group { "developers":
        gid => 1001;
      }
    }

    # modules/users/manifests/account.pp
    define users::account($ensure=present, managehome='true', allowdupe='false', homeprefix='/home', $username, $name, $password, $uid, $gid, $groups=[], $key='', $keytype='ssh-rsa', shell='/bin/zsh') {

      File { owner => $username, group => $username, mode => '0600' }

      $home = "${homeprefix}/${username}"

      user { $username:
        ensure     => $ensure,
        uid        => $uid,
        gid        => $gid,
        password   => $password,
        comment    => "$name",
        groups     => $groups,
        shell      => "$shell",
        home       => $home,
        require    => Group["$gid"],
        allowdupe  => $allowdupe,
        managehome => $managehome;
      }

      file { "$home":
        ensure => directory
      }
      if $key {
        file { "$home/.ssh":
            ensure => directory;
        }
        ssh_authorized_key { "$username":
          user    => $username,
          require => File["$home/.ssh"],
          key     => $key,
          type    => $keytype,
          ensure  => present;
        }
      }
    }
```

If this is a dependency issue, what's the best way to specify dependencies? Or am I doing something else wrong? General feedback would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puppet is probably not even trying to create the user, because you are making a virtual **user::account** resource (where you specify the "@"), but are only trying to realize a **user** resource (there are no virtual **user** resources).

Further, the filter **group == developer** would not match anything as there is no **group** attribute on either **user**, or **user::account**.

Try substituting **User <| group == developer |>** with **Users::Account <| gid == developer |>** and see if that helps.

Comment: That was spot on, thanks very much. Silly mistakes are the easiest to fix :)